# Radial circuit vs ring main

Tags: wiring

I have a developed an old stable, a wood clad barn, to become habitable, but unfortunately, one of the builders appears to have put a screw through from the outside and damaged part of the ring main within. It has apparently severed the neutral wire in the cable.

My electrician has suggested that rather than repairing the broken section (it would require a major part of the building to be taken apart to find and replace the offending cable), he could rewire, at the circuit breaker box, the two ends of the ring main into separate circuit breakers, and treat it as two radial circuits.

I am concerned at whether this solution would be safe.... The earth, and live wires are obviously still intact. I think it is supposition on the part of the electrician that the cable has been nicked at a particular spot , and I am also concerned that if I touch the offending screw, I will be electrocuted, as the live is still intact.

No doubt, there will be many that simply suggest that this electrician is a cowboy, to offer such a solution. However, if we can get beyond that, I'd like to understand the electrical risks.  Many thanks, Garry.

Comment: To be safe, I think you'd have to disconnect the damaged section of the cable by severing it at the adjacent two outlets or accessible junction boxes. Unless the break is in the middle of the ring, I suspect the longer radial will need downrating as the cable might not be thick enough for the number of outlets. Is the electrician registered and able to sign the certification for the modification?

Comment: Yes, that's useful, thanks.  He is indeed registered, but possibly under some pressure from the project manager to find a "fast" and "least expensive" resolution.  Hence I wished to know about the safety issues.

Comment: I'd consider getting an independent electrician to do an Electrical Installation Condition Report (EICR) of the amended installation. Ideally the insurers of whoever made the mistake that caused the problem (unprotected cable or screws in wrong place) should pay for this (and any remedial work that gets flagged up).

Comment: Good points, Thank you! My first time on this forum, and I'm impressed by speed of response.  Very helpful in how I will tackle the issue with the main contractor in the morning!

Comment: Part of the reason for using a ring main is so that you can use smaller conductors as some of the current travels both directions in the wiring. As long as the breakers are sized appropriately for the installation, I don't see a safety problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.   I now understand that, because the breaker box is fully occupied, both strands of the now severed ring main come back and terminate at the same contact breaker.  However, the electrician has downgraded the breaker itself from a 38amp (?) to a 20 amp.  Two questions ... is it ok for the two radials to terminate at the same breaker? And, Given that this is a studio, containing several PCs and other equipment, recording gear and multiple guitar amplifiers, is 20amp going to be enough ?  At peak times, all would be in use concurrently.  Many thanks, Garry

Comment: A bigger concern I have is that you have an unknown fault somewhere that has not been repaired. At a minimum, the faulty wiring needs to be disconnected and removed. If the problem is a screw that penetrated one conductor, then it's possible that it could penetrate another in the future and cause a short and possibly a fire.